# What is the correct way to handle REST style mapping in this Spring Boot\MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application that implements REST web services.

So I have the following doubt about the URL that have to be used to handle insertion of an item in the database.

So basially I have this controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/AccomodationMedia")
public class AccomodationMediaController {

    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................
    ..............................................................

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   @RequestParam MultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("handleFileUpload() START");
        if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
            for (MultipartFile currentFile : fileUpload){

                System.out.println("Saving file: " + currentFile.getOriginalFilename());

                accomodationMediaService.saveAccomodationMedia(currentFile);

            }
        }

        return "Success";
    }

}
```

So, this class contains the **handleFileUpload()** method that handle **POST** Http request toward the URI: **/AccomodationMedia/doUpload** to upload a file.

This URI is not in rest style because it contains an action and in this case I have to handle it as resoure.

My doubt is: I think that to insert a new **AccomodationMedia** resource I only have to handhe **POST** requesto toward the **/AccomodationMedia** URI because I am inserting a new **AccountMedia** resource in the database. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you are correct, each resource in a rest application should have at least one URI identifying it. And it's best when that URI makes sense and adequately describes the resource, just for example :-

To insert (create) a new customer in the system, we might use:
POST http://www.example.com/customers

To read a customer with Customer ID# 33245:
GET http://www.example.com/customers/33245 The same URI would be used for PUT and DELETE, to update and delete, respectively.